# Converting an ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php, deprecated

I have to convert an `ereg_replace` to `preg_replace`

The ereg_replace code is:

```
ereg_replace( '\$([0-9])', '&#36;\1', $value );
```

As preg is denoted by a start and end backslash I assume the conversion is:

```
preg_replace( '\\$([0-9])\', '&#36;\1', $value );
```

As I don't have a good knowledge of regex I'm not sure if the above is the correct method to use?

Answer (score 15):

One of the differences between `ereg_replace()` and `preg_replace()` is that the pattern must be enclosed by delimiters: `delimiter + pattern + delimiter`. As stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), *a delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, **non-backslash**, non-whitespace character*. This means that valid delimiters are: `/`, `#`, `~`, `+`, `%`, `@`, `!` and `<>`, with the first two being most often used (but this is just my guess).

If your `ereg_replace()` worked as you expected, then simply add delimiters to the pattern and it will do the thing. All examples below will work:

```
preg_replace('/\$([0-9])/', '&#36;\1', $value);
```

or

```
preg_replace('#\$([0-9])#', '&#36;\1', $value);
```

or

```
preg_replace('%\$([0-9])%', '&#36;\1', $value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that - it's like getting more pieces to the puzzle as I'm upgrading from PHP 5.2.9 and noticed the DEPRECATED messages when using PHP 3 or above.

Comment: Thank you for the *clear*, and concise explanation. Not being an expert, they looked the same to me and only this answer explains the *actual* difference. (I realize this is nearly 10 years later `:)` )

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_replace( '#\$([0-9])#', '\$$1', $value );
```

Comment: Thanks for that insight - it all helps