# How to convert special ereg_replace functions

Tags: regex, php-7

How can I convert / update the following regular expression functions to be valid in PHP 7:

```
$rawsub=ereg_replace("</*b>", "", $subject);

$qauthor=ereg_replace("<b>|</b>", "", $author);

$body=eregi_replace("<(mailto:)([^ >\n\t]+)>", "{phopen}a href=\"\\1\\2\"{phclose}\\2{phopen}/a{phclose}", $body);

$body=eregi_replace("<([http|news|ftp]+://[^ >\n\t]+)>", "{phopen}a href=\"\\1\"{phclose}\\1{phopen}/a{phclose}", $body);

$body=eregi_replace("<(/*($ForumAllowHTML) *[^>]*)>", "{phopen}\\1{phclose}", $body);
```

Comment: These regular expression look like they lack delimiters (i.e. `/`)?  Are these throwing errors?  If so, please [edit] your question to include the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for **preg_replace()** instead of using **ereg_replace()** and rewrite your pattern according to **preg_replace()**. For more details, you can visit this link below.
[preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace)

[Difference between preg_replace() and ereg_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159990/converting-an-ereg-replace-to-preg-replace)

Comment: Thank you. How are the correct commands?

Comment: $rawsub=preg_replace("#</*b>#", "", $subject);

Comment: $qauthor=preg_replace("(<b>|</b>)", "", $author);

Comment: $body=preg_replace("/<(mailto:)([^ >\n\t]+)>/i", "{phopen}a href=\"\\1\\2\"{phclose}\\2{phopen}/a{phclose}", $body);

Comment: $body=preg_replace("#<([http|news|ftp]+://[^ >\n\t]+)>#i", "{phopen}a href=\"\\1\"{phclose}\\1{phopen}/a{phclose}", $body);

Comment: $body=preg_replace("#<(/*($ForumAllowHTML) *[^>]*)>#i", "{phopen}\\1{phclose}", $body);

Comment: ARE THESE ANSWERS CORRECT?

Comment: commands are almost same to the previous, just need to change a bit.....like $text = ereg_replace('[^A-Z0-9]', '', $text ); it will be changed to $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/', '', $text ); for easy to understand [click here](http://www.w3programmers.com/working-with-php-regular-expression/)

Comment: Didn't you see my solution (comments above)???